# A brainfuck interpreter in C

Tags: c, brainfuck

I wrote  brainfuck interpreter in order to prepare myself for a C job. I try to write the code as clear and as defensively as I can. Can somebody take a look at the code and give me some hints for improvement?

```
// tape.h
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Tape {
    long pointer;
    long capacity;
    unsigned short *data;
} Tape;


void initializeTape(Tape *tape);

void growTape(Tape *tape);

void incrementPointer(Tape *tape);

void decrementPointer(Tape *tape);

void incrementValue(Tape *tape);

void decrementValue(Tape *tape);

void read(Tape *tape);

void get(Tape *tape);

void freeTape(Tape *tape);

long interpret(Tape *tape, const char *source_code, long source_code_size, long position);
```

The implementation of `tape.h`

```
// tape.c
#include "tape.h"

void initializeTape(Tape *tape) {
    tape->pointer = 0;
    tape->capacity = 8;
    tape->data = (unsigned short *) calloc( tape->capacity, sizeof(unsigned short));
    if (tape->data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void growTape(Tape *tape) {
    tape->capacity *= 2;
    tape->data = (unsigned short *) realloc(tape->data, tape->capacity);
    if (tape->data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void incrementPointer(Tape *tape) {
    if (tape->pointer >= tape->capacity) {
        growTape(tape);
    }
    tape->pointer++;
}

void decrementPointer(Tape *tape) {
    if (tape->pointer == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error. Negative pointer detected.");
        exit(1);
    }
    tape->pointer--;
}

void incrementValue(Tape *tape) {
    tape->data[tape->pointer]++;
}

void decrementValue(Tape *tape) {
    tape->data[tape->pointer]--;
}

void read(Tape *tape) {
    putchar(tape->data[tape->pointer]);
}

void get(Tape *tape) {
    tape->data[tape->pointer] = (char) getchar();
}

void freeTape(Tape *tape) {
    free(tape->data);
    tape->pointer = 0;
    tape->capacity = 0;
}

long interpret(Tape *tape, const char *source_code, long source_code_size, long position) {
    char c = source_code[position];
    switch (c) {
        case '>':
            incrementPointer(tape);
            break;
        case '<':
            decrementPointer(tape);
            break;
        case '+':
            incrementValue(tape);
            break;
        case '-':
            decrementValue(tape);
            break;
        case '.':
            read(tape);
            break;
        case ',':
            get(tape);
            break;
        case '[':
            if (tape->data[tape->pointer] == (char) 0) {
                int stack = 1;
                long j = position + 1;
                for (; j < source_code_size && stack > 0 && tape->pointer < source_code_size; j++) {
                    char _c = source_code[j];
                    if (_c == '[') {
                        ++stack;
                    } else if (_c == ']') {
                        --stack;
                    }
                }
                if (stack != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error. Missing closing ].\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    position = j + 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case ']':
            if (tape->data[tape->pointer] != (char) 0) {
                int stack = 1;
                long j = position - 1;
                for (; j >= 0 && stack > 0 && tape->pointer >= 0; j--) {
                    char _c = source_code[j];
                    if (_c == '[') {
                        --stack;
                    } else if (_c == ']') {
                        ++stack;
                    }
                }
                if (stack != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error. Missing opening [.\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    position = j + 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ++position;
}
```

And the `main` file:

```
// main.c
#include "tape.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file;
    if (argc < 2) {
        file = fopen("helloworld.bf", "r");
    } else {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to fseek file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    long filesize = ftell(file);
    if (filesize < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to read file's size\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rewind(file);

    char source_code[filesize];
    size_t result = fread(source_code, 1, filesize, file);

    if (fclose(file) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not close file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (result != filesize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not read file. Corrupt\n");
    }

    Tape tape;
    initializeTape(&tape);
    long i = 0;

    while(i < filesize) {
        i = interpret(&tape, source_code, filesize, i);
    }
    freeTape(&tape);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: don’t throw away the original pointer when calling realloc(), because if it fails, you might still want to access (or free) the original data. You normally see something like `void *newptr = realloc(...); if ( newptr ) data = newptr; else handle_nomemory();`

Comment: With a little dyslexia, the title of this question suggests that one implemented a C interpreter in brainflak... which would be quite astonishing, and certainly imply enough knowledge of C for a job!

Comment: A syntax error is a specific kind of error; a negative tape pointer isn't one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Overall Observations

An interpreter should be able to read from standard in as well as from a file, this would break the entire tape model. The user could also redirect an input file to standard in.

If you are going to program in C then you need to get comfortable with pointers.

In the case of file input I would use an algorithm that reads a line at a time, that way the file doesn't need to be read twice and the memory used to store the file doesn't need to be allocated. Reading a line at a time will also work for console input. If you are use C in an embedded environment allocating the space to store the memory could seriously affect the amount of memory available for processing. For this reason you also need to be careful when using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` in an embedded environment. Some embedded C compilers do not support memory allocation and some companies will have coding standards that do not include memory allocation for embedded applications.

### Only Include Headers Needed to Make the Code Compile

The header file `tape.h` includes `assert.h` and `assert()` is not used in the program. Since the C pre-processor implementation of include is generally to create a temporary source file and actually copy the included header files this increases the size of the temporary source files without need and increases compile time.

Hiding `#include` statements within other include files can sometimes lead to problems, include files that are necessary to make the header compile and `tape.h` doesn't need any header files to compile. An example of when it would be necessary to include a header file in `tape.h` is if there were functions that returned type `bool` and then the header file should contain the statement `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Make it clear what each C source file needs to compile by including the headers in the C source file.

As a side note, it is better not to use `assert` since if the code is optimized all asserts will be optimized out of the code.

### Performance (speed)

In the main loop of the program and in the function `interpret()` execution time might be improved if you used character pointers rather than integer indexing. In addition to possibly improving the performance this could also decrease the amount of code in the function `interpret()` by reducing the number of temporary variables. Note the following code has not been tested and may not work.

In `main()`:

```
    char* current_source_code_ptr = source_code;
    char* end_file_ptr = &source_code[filesize - 1];
    while (current_source_code_ptr < end_file_ptr) {
        current_source_code_ptr = interpret(current_source_code_ptr, end_file_ptr, source_code, &tape);
    }

char* interpret(char* current_source_code_ptr, const char* end_file_ptr, const char *source_code, Tape* tape) {
    switch (*current_source_code_ptr) {
    case '>':
        incrementPointer(tape);
        break;
    case '<':
        decrementPointer(tape);
        break;
    case '+':
        incrementValue(tape);
        break;
    case '-':
        decrementValue(tape);
        break;
    case '.':
        read(tape);
        break;
    case ',':
        get(tape);
        break;
    case '[':
        if (tape->data[tape->pointer] == (char)0) {
            int stack = 1;
            for (; current_source_code_ptr < end_file_ptr && stack > 0 && tape->pointer < (end_file_ptr - source_code); current_source_code_ptr++) {
                if (*current_source_code_ptr == '[') {
                    ++stack;
                }
                else if (*current_source_code_ptr == ']') {
                    --stack;
                }
            }
            if (stack != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error. Missing closing ].\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else {
                current_source_code_ptr++;
            }
        }
        break;
    case ']':
        if (tape->data[tape->pointer] != (char)0) {
            int stack = 1;
            for (; current_source_code_ptr >= source_code && stack > 0 && tape->pointer >= 0; current_source_code_ptr--) {
                if (*current_source_code_ptr == '[') {
                    --stack;
                }
                else if (*current_source_code_ptr == ']') {
                    ++stack;
                }
            }
            if (stack != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error. Missing opening [.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else {
                current_source_code_ptr++;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return ++current_source_code_ptr;
}
```

### Complexity

The switch/case statement in the function `interpret()` is too long, each case should be implemented by a function, so the code for `case '[':` and `case ']':` should be moved into separate functions.

### Use System Defined Constants

The header file `stdlib.h` includes system specific definitions for the macros [EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status). This would make the code more readable and possibly more portable.

// main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tape.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* file;
    if (argc < 2) {
        file = fopen("helloworld.bf", "r");
    }
    else {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to fseek file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    long filesize = ftell(file);
    if (filesize < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to read file's size\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    rewind(file);

    char source_code[filesize];
    size_t result = fread(source_code, 1, filesize, file);

    if (fclose(file) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not close file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (result != filesize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not read file. Corrupt\n");
    }

    Tape tape;
    initializeTape(&tape);
    long i = 0;

    while (i < filesize) {
        i = interpret(&tape, source_code, filesize, i);
    }
    freeTape(&tape);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "_a line at a time, ... doesn't need to be allocated_" - does Brainfuck have a strict line length limit, then?

Comment: I would be careful in assuming pointer arithmetic is more efficient than pointer + integer offset. Often CPUs have native instructions handling pointer + offset from register. And if the compiler can inline everything, it probably won't make any difference at all. In this case, it doesn't matter much, except checking whether the end of the tape is reached in `incrementPointer()` and `decrementPointer()` is IMO slightly nicer to write using offsets than using pointers.

Answer (score 13):

## Only include the header files that you need

Looking at `tape.h`, it only contains declarations and no definitions. As such, the header files only serve to bloat up the source code and increase compilation time. You should move them to `tape.c`.

## Use `static` methods if possible

If I look at `main.c`, the only functions that are utilized are `initializeTape`, `interpret` and `freeTape`. These are the only functions that form the interface. You could move the other functions into `tape.c` and declare them `static`. Remember, header files should only contain the necessary functions.

## Use fixed width integers from <stdint.h>

I'm not a fan of using data types such as `long`, `unsigned short`, `long long` since the standard makes no guarantees about the actual size of these types; only the minimum size. Prefer using fixed types such as `int64_t`, `uint16_t`, `intptr_t`, etc.

## `initializeTape` and `growTape` should not exit

Imagine being a user trying to use your code in one of their projects. If you fail to allocate, the program will exit and will not give the user control on how to deal with the error.

Consider returning a value based on whether memory was successfully allocated, such as 0 or -1, or even `true` or `false` if you have access to C99. That way, the user can check and decide what to do in case of failure.

```
if(!initializeTape(&tape))
{
    // Do some error handling here
}
```

## You don't have to cast to `unsigned short *` after allocating

Not a problem, but I should mention that it is not necessary to cast to the desired type after allocating as `void*` is implicitly convertible to other pointer types.

## Check `tape == NULL` in `freeTape`

This could lead to potential segfaults if you're not careful.

Comment: _tape.h only contains declarations and no definitions._ - Yeah - that's the point. It should stay like this; that's the standard thing to do, and mashing those into the `.c` file will not buy you much compilation efficiency, assuming that we're not living in the 1970s.

Comment: The standard does make some guarantees about the range of values that can be represented by the built-in types.  Fixed-width types such as `int64_t` are usually a poor choice, especially compared to `int_fast64_t`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `perror()` to give more useful information from library-call failures.  For example, consider

> ```
> if (file == NULL) {
>     fprintf(stderr, "Can not open file %s\n", argv[1]);
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
> }
> ```

We could get better error message (e.g. "file not found", "permission denied", etc) like this:

```
if (!file) {
    perror(argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: But `perror()` unfortunately doesn't show what the filename was. You can write `fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno))`, or if you're on Linux or BSD there's the very convenient [`err()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html), sadly not standard C.

Comment: Yes @G.Sliepen, though in my example, it does show the filename (at the expense of not showing which operation failed).  I do usually end up using `fprintf()` with `strerror()` as you show (or, in GNU environments `fprintf()` with `%m`).

Answer (score 2):

In general your code looks reasonable, there is only one thing that you need to keep for your self for future devs. In general, your function initializeTape and the rest of the file tape.c

```
void initializeTape(Tape *tape) {
    tape->pointer = 0;
    tape->capacity = 8;
    tape->data = (unsigned short *) calloc( tape->capacity, sizeof(unsigned short));
    if (tape->data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

should check that the pointer tape is not null

```
void initializeTape(Tape *tape) {
    if (tape) {
        tape->pointer = 0;
        tape->capacity = 8;
        tape->data = (unsigned short *) calloc( tape->capacity, sizeof(unsigned short));
        if (tape->data == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } // else exit(-1) or whatever you choose
}
```

This will remove potentially issues (invalid pointer) if you extend your code.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's normal for functions that take a pointer arg to require it to be non-NULL without checking for it, e.g. `fprintf` itself will just crash if you pass a NULL pointer for either of its first 2 args.  There's nothing useful you can do in this function other than exit as a debug check.  But dereferencing a NULL pointer will fairly reliably crash on most implementations, so just do that, and let people use a debugger to find where they're passing a NULL pointer from, if it ever happens.